# Time data granularity in long term forecasting

Tags: regression, forecasting, dataset

I am using weather (know to have correlation with energy usage) and customer population size to forecast energy usage 20 years out, by year. Currently, I am using annual average weather variables to forecast at year with regression. However, I have access to daily and even hourly weather data.

I am wondering if I am loosing valuable forecasting power by using yearly weather averages. Would it be more appropriate to use monthly weather to predict out 20 years into the future by predicting months and then summing the 12 predictions for the year?

Comment: It probably won't make much difference. If your goal is to estimate annual averages, then predicting the annual averages or averaging the annual predictions will give approximately the same if not identical results.